# Redefining a handle ptr of void* to handle ptr to struct* (C/C++ mixcode) for access

Tags: c++, c, class, typedef, void-pointers

I have C/C++ mix code and want to pass around a struct that contains a reference to a class. Because of this, I can't declare this struct in the header file of the C++ component (because class is defined in source file of C++ component) but only in the source file. The main script in C however has to reference that struct somehow, so I typedef it to void*. However because of that, I can't dereference the handle type back to a struct. Redefining the handle pointer in the source file is not possible. How can I work around this?

**header_with_obj.hpp**

```
class A {
    int a;
};
```

**header.hpp**

```
typedef void* config_handle_t;
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include "header.hpp"
#include "header_with_obj.hpp"

typedef struct {
    A* ptr;
    int some_other;
} config_t;

// typedef config_t* config_handle_t <-- error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct config_t* config_handle_t '

int foo(void* arg)
{
    config_handle_t handle = (config_handle_t) arg;
    handle->A.a = 4; //  <-- error: 'config_handle_t' {aka 'void*'} is not a pointer-to-object type
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "header.hpp"

int main()
{
    // we get that void* from somewhere and pass it in
    foo(arg);
}
```

Comment: You can do it without any casting at all: Put this in `header.hpp`: `typedef struct config_t* config_handle_t;` Pointers to incomplete types are valid in both C and C++. And you preserve type safety (somebody can't accidentally pass an `int*`).

Comment: how? I get  `error: unknown type name 'config_t'
 typedef config_t* config_handle_t;`
Which makes sense because the declaration of struct config_t is in source file.

Comment: @glades you wrote config_t instead of struct config_t. Also you would have to declare the struct as `struct config_t {...};` instead of `typedef struct {...} config_t;` because in the second one the struct technically doesn't have a name.

Comment: @RaymondChen this is the correct answer: you should make it an answer not a comment.

Comment: @user253751: thank you that worked now! What a subtle difference, but I always wondered what the difference of typedef and struct actually was. I think I will have to change some malloc(sizeof(config_t)) to malloc (sizeof(struct config_t)) now if I remember correctly?

Comment: @glades you can also add `typedef struct config_t config_t;` or use `typedef struct config_t {...} config_t;`

Comment: @user253751: Oh I didn't know you could use the same name. This way I don't need to change anything. Can you put your answer including those comments? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to use an undefined struct. In its most basic form:

```
void foo(struct the_config_struct *arg);
// OK even though 'struct the_config_struct' wasn't defined!
// surprisingly this is also allowed in C++
```

You can also make a typedef:

```
typedef struct the_config_struct *config_handle_t;
void foo(config_handle_t arg);
```

and if you want, you can even call the typedef the same thing as the struct. Just to avoid confusing people, I wouldn't do this unless it's a typedef *for the struct* (not a pointer).

```
typedef struct the_config_struct the_config_struct;
void foo(the_config_struct *arg);
```

You don't to actually have defined the struct until you want to access its members:

```
// if we uncomment this definition then it's OK
// struct my_struct {
//     char *message;
// };

void foo(struct my_struct *arg) {
    puts(arg->message); // error: struct my_struct is undefined
}
```

Finally (since this confused you before) you should know that typedef names and struct names are completely separate in C.

```
struct foo {}; // defines "struct foo" but "foo" is completely unrelated
typedef int bar; // defines "bar" but "struct bar" is completely unrelated

foo *get_foo(); // error: "foo" is unknown
struct foo *get_foo(); // OK

typedef struct bar foo;
foo *get_bar(); // OK: returns pointer to struct bar (not struct foo!)
struct foo *get_foo(); // this one returns pointer to struct foo

struct baz {};
typedef struct baz baz;
// now "baz" is an alternative name for "struct baz" - they are interchangeable

typedef struct baz {} baz; // short version
```

and structs don't have to have names:

```
// foo is a variable, and it's a struct variable, but the struct has no name.
// so we have no way to use the struct for anything else.
struct {
    int i;
} foo;

// The struct is still there even though it doesn't have a name!
// In C++ you can write decltype(bar) to say "the same type as variable bar".
// Even though we don't know the person's name we can still yell out "Hey you in the red shirt!"
decltype(foo) foo2; // a variable foo2. The type is decltype(foo) i.e. the struct from before

// GCC lets you do it in C using "typeof".
// This is not standard. It's a special feature in GCC.
typeof(foo) foo2;

// This struct also has no name either. But the typedef means we have
// an "unofficial" way to name it, just like decltype(foo) before.
// This is valid in C as well as C++.
typedef struct {
    char message[50];
} bar;
```